# spyder kernel does not launch on spyder startup

Tags: python, spyder

If I start a spyder kernel with the command :

```
python -m spyder_kernels.console
```

and then connect to it from spyder using "connect to an existing kernel", everything works

**BUT** the kernel cannot launch automatically on spyder startup, it spits back :

```
 ModuleNotFoundError : Cannot find spyder_kernels module.
```

I work with a separate python installation with all modules placed in $PYTHONPATH folder.

### versions used :

- python3.8.10
- spyder 5.4.4
- spyder-kernels 2.4.4

### logs gathered from spyder debug mode :

```
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Instantiating kernel 'Python 3 (Spyder)' with kernel provisioner: local-provisioner
[INFO] [spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.utils.kernelspec] -> Kernel command: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '{connection_file}']
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Starting kernel: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '/home/user1/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-44f34965291d.json']
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:40848
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> connecting heartbeat channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:37351
[INFO] [spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.utils.kernelspec] -> Kernel command: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '{connection_file}']
[INFO] [spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.utils.kernelspec] -> Kernel command: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '{connection_file}']
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Using default logger
[DEBUG] [asyncio] -> Using selector: EpollSelector
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> connecting shell channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:46658
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:46658
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> connecting iopub channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:32775
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:32775
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> connecting stdin channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:43099
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:43099
[DEBUG] [asyncio] -> Using selector: EpollSelector
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> connecting control channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:51428
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:51428
[DEBUG] [spyder.plugins.editor.utils.autosave] -> Autosave triggered
[INFO] [traitlets] -> KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
[INFO] [spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.utils.kernelspec] -> Kernel command: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '{connection_file}']
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Starting kernel: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '/home/user1/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-44f34965291d.json']
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:40848
[INFO] [traitlets] -> KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (5/5), new random ports
[INFO] [spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.utils.kernelspec] -> Kernel command: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '{connection_file}']
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Starting kernel: ['/path/to/bin/python3', '-Xfrozen_modules=off', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '/home/user1/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-44f34965291d.json']
[DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:40848
[WARNING] [traitlets] -> KernelRestarter: restart failed
[WARNING] [traitlets] -> kernel died: 25.00089931488037
[DEBUG] [asyncio] -> Using selector: EpollSelector
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You said `I work with a separate python installation with all modules placed in $PYTHONPATH folder.`. That's not the right way to use a different Python installation in Spyder. For that, please remove all additions you did to PYTHONPATH and instead follow [our instructions](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) about it.